# How to check/validate and avoid creating multiple records, when i have multiple containers running for same application service

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, distributed

We have an application service that is running on two or more pods, i.e., two or more instances of the service running simultaneously. Application requests can go to any of the running instance of the app.

We have an

- API that creates some kind of `allotment` records - first does validation and then inserts data into database table
- Validation in the API - it should perform an insert only when the total amount of these allotment records should not exceed 500K, i.e. total value of allotments should not cross 500K

Now it worked fine when we have one instance of service running (we could handle concurrent requests via java synchronization)

However now that we have two or more instances of the service running, we can have simultaneous requests being routed to multiple instances of same service.

- Each application service fetches existing records, does validation and then inserts.
- If we have 3 requests going simultaneously to three different application instances, each will pass validation and then create their records.
- This results in the allotments being done in excess of 500K, even though each application service did the validation first and then inserted the data.

Since these are concurrent requests that are processed by different instances of the application server, how do we validate and prevent this from happening?

**NOTE** : Database trigger is not an option for us, unless it the only available option.
We want to implement some kind of logic at application layer.

If it was an database update instead of database insert, we could have implemented a lock on the db record. But since this is an insert, how do we implement the check and avoid creating such records.

Comment: I would start from [here](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html), but there are many ways that attempts to solve this. Research more. I don't think an objective answer can be provided without knowing the arch/design decisions that has already been made in the system.

Comment: Don't you just need to perform the validation and the update in the same database transaction?

Comment: When validating that the total amount is below 500k, is that a global total, or is it scoped to some parent key? In other words, do all of these requests need to be handled sequentially, or is there some way to partition them into independent groups?

Comment: @StephenC yes the validation and insert into db happens within same db transaction. There is no update. Consider that sum of current allotments is 250K. 
Now there are two simultaneous requests to add 200K of allotments. Each request goes to different app server, passes the validation (as current is less than 250K), and then both of them insert into the db resulting in total allotment being now 650K which is incorrect

Comment: @TimMoore Each allotment add some amount. E.g allotment 1 added 100k, allotment2 added 50K and so on. The sum of all these allotments should not cross 500K. 
Yes ideally if all requests are handled sequentially then the problem will not arise. 
However since requests can go to different servers simultaneously so there is no way to block other requests while one request is processing

Comment: @aksappy thanks for the link. Implementing this would be very big change for our application. Ours is a simple java spring boot application which exposes a POST API to create allotment records. For availability we have 2-3 instance of same application running. Due to this there can be many concurrent requests for same POST api, that goes to different instances of the same application. 
I was looking for way to add sequential behaviour to this POST API - meaning at a time only one of them should be processed even if requests go to different instances of the application server at the same time

Comment: @SunitChatterjee - I think you are using the wrong kind of transaction isolation level then.  I think you should use TIL "serializable" and do the database reads that get data for validation in the same database transaction as the inserts or updates.   That will lock the row ranges that are used for validation until the transaction commits (or is rolled back).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels

Comment: The point is ... solve the consistency problem in the database not the application server instances.

Comment: Thanks @StephenC
My isolation level was READ_COMMITTED,  i will try with SERIAZABLE